# Procedure executing 10 times faster using job agent

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, jobs

I have got procedure that does some inserts with selects. When i try to run it from Access or even in management studio it takes 4 minutes. With job checking every 40 sec if there is that procedure to execute and executing it it took around 15 sec.

What can cause a problem? Why the same procedure executed from job is 10 times faster than procedure executed from access or query in management studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is any time difference here. The problem is that after the job runs a few times, then the data is likely cached in memory, and thus it runs very fast.

You do a fresh re-boot and then check the time for the run, it should be the SAME from all sources.

It is not clear how you are calling this routine, but is it possible that the job scheduling is NOT waiting for the routine to finish?

And does the routine return any data to the client application? Perhaps the difference is that when run from Access (or SSMS) then lots of data is returned from the stored procedure, but when run using job agent, then NO provisions exist to consume the returned data, so the returning of data is ignored and thus the result(s) run faster.